# Jquery Animated 2-Pane Div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, jsfiddle, panes

SO,

I'm working on integrating the two-pane DIVs using Jquery detailed by David Walsh [here](http://davidwalsh.name/google-extension-effect). I've migrated his code to a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/3BMfu/11/) and made some adjustments but the animation doesn't seem to be working. If anyone has any idea what I'm missing in the code I'd greatly appreciate input!

-Marca

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".itemJQuery").bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
      var self = jQuery(this), billboard = self.data("billboardElement");
      if(!billboard) {
        billboard = jQuery(jQuery(".item-billboard", this)[0]);
        self.data("billboardElement", billboard);
      }
      jQuery(billboard).stop().animate({
        "margin-top": "-200px"
      });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      jQuery(this).data("billboardElement").stop().animate({
        "margin-top": 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-billboard">
      <h3>Angry Birds</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item-detail">
      <p>There's more detail about the item inside this DIV!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {position: relative;width: 240px;overflow: hidden;border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.item {height: 200px;}      
.item a {text-decoration: none;color: #000;}     
.item-billboard, .item-detail {padding: 10px;height: 180px;}     
.item-billboard {margin-top: 0;background: red;}
.item-billboard h3 {font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;color: #262626;font-family: "Open Sans", arial, sans-serif;}
.item-detail {background: #ececec;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about David Walsh but here at SO we build stuff like this :)

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uxizew/5/edit)*

```
$('.item').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
    $(this).stop().animate({scrollTop: e.type=='mouseenter'?200:0 }, 400);    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `jQuery(".itemJQuery")` to `jQuery(".item")` and it works.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/3BMfu/12/